# How to make booteable usb?

Tags: 14.04, live-usb

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 and I want to make a live USB for another linux distro, but I don't know how to. In Windows I used [LiLi](http://www.linuxliveusb.com/en/download) but sadly it doesn't work on linux.

How can I make a live USB for my desired linux distro?

Comment: TRy Usb creator.http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to create a bootable disk in Ubuntu then no need to download any tool. In dash (press Windows key in keyboard ) search **Start up Disk Creator** tool and open it. then select the correct ISO file from where it is stored and select the USB drive you want to create the bootable USB. Finally  click "make start up disk".

Official instructions with pictures: http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

Try Unetbootin.

Ubuntu: `sudo apt-get install unetbootin` [in the universe repos]

Unetbootin PPA: https://launchpad.net/~gezakovacs/+archive/ubuntu/ppa

Unetbootin Website: http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/